# Qual è il significato di "strepenato" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives, regional

Nella commedia *Morte accidentale di un anarchico* di Dario Fo, pubblicata da Einaudi, ho letto queste parole pronunciate dal Matto, che si sta facendo passare per un capitano della polizia scientifica:

> Ma cosa si aspetta, signorina, con queste sue palesi provocazioni? Che le si
>   risponda ammettendo che qualora noi della polizia,
>   invece di perderci dietro a quei quattro anarchici **strepenati** ci si fosse preoccupati di seguire seriamente altre piste piú attendibili, tipo organizzazioni paramilitari e fasciste finanziate dagli industriali, dirette e
>   appoggiate da militari e circonvicini, forse si sarebbe
>   venuti a capo della matassa?

La mia domanda è sul senso dell'aggettivo "strepenato" in questo passaggio. Non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Si tratta forse di un termine di origine dialettale?

Comment: Charo: Dario Fo's language is very non-standard and full of regionalisms, as you have seen. Many words are literally invented. I would not recommend it to an Italian learner. There are many writers that you could read to help improve your (already very good) Italian, but I am afraid Dario Fo isn't a good choice. You risk learning bad habits and dubious words from him.

Comment: Non ti preoccupare, @FedericoPoloni, anni fa ho letto molto Camilleri e non per questo ho finito per parlare come Catarella :). Quindi, penso di essere in grado di leggere Dario Fo senza imparare queste "cattive abitudini". Infatti voglio leggerlo perché lo trovo assolutamente geniale! E, per quanto riguarda il mio italiano, non credo possa arrivare mai alla categoria di "non learner".

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Devi anche sapere che la lettura di *Morte accidentale di un anarchico* faceva parte del corso che ho fatto un anno fa per ottenere il certificato d'Italiano di livello C1. Durante questo corso dovevamo leggere parecchi libri di generi letterari diversi. Quando è arrivato il turno del teatro, ci hanno dato una lista di raccomandazioni tra le quali c'erano alcune opere di Dario Fo.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Inoltre, l'esame che ho dovuto fare per ottenere il certificato d'Italiano di livello C1 aveva anche a che fare, soprattutto nella parte di comprensione orale, con l'essere in grado di capire questi curiosi italiani che si esprimono usando tanti regionalismi e hanno una pronuncia non-standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo stesso Dario Fo, in un'altra delle sue opere, il racconto *Il primo miracolo di Gesú Bambino* (versione in italiano), di *Mistero Buffo*, scrive:

> Arriva il Gesú bambino con il moccio al naso... fin sulla bocca, tutto **strapennato** [stracciato], con le mani zozze, le braghe di traverso, senza neanche una scarpa ai piedi.

Nel libro appare questa nota: «Le versioni fra parentesi quadre servono ai traduttori in lingua straniera per una piú chiara comprensione del testo».

Il vocabolo che si trova nella versione originale di questo racconto che, secondo spiega lo stesso Fo, è scritta in "un linguaggio che è l'insieme di parecchi dialetti del Nord tra i quali prevale il veneto",
è "strapenàdo". Si tratta dunque di un termine di origine dialettale.

Quindi, come indicato da @CarLaTeX, il significato di questo termine in questo contesto è conciato male, stracciato, ridotto in brandelli, cencioso...

Infatti, sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([[1]](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000299.jpg) e [[2]](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000300.jpg)), si trova:

> **2.** *Per estens.* Vestito di panni laceri o logori (una persona). – Anche sostant. 
>       *Chiesa*, 5-8: La mamma... insisteva che per quegli strapanati fosse fin troppo la camera della povera zia Lia. *Linati*, 16-82: Uno  era  un  vecchietto  rubizzo,  dalle  gambe  a  ròncolo,  strapa­nato  e  bisunto. *Palazzeschi*,
>     II-744:  Quei  fanciulli  strapanati, cisposi,  piagnucolenti,  ai  quali  non  si  può nemmeno  dare  un bacio senza correre il rischio di sbagliare il sito.

La cosa curiosa è che il GDLI dà "strapanato" come toscanismo.

Answer (score 3):

Dal dialetto milanese, "vestito male".

Una fonte:

http://it.cultura.linguistica.italiano.narkive.com/POyEsPCr/dialetto-strepenaa

Comment: Ma questa fonte è veramente affidabile?

Comment: Ho sentito usare l'aggettivo strepenaa nel dialetto delle mie parti sia con il significato di spettinato, malvestito, disordinato, sia con quello di spiantato economicamente. Strepenato è chiaramente una italianizzazione dello stesso aggettivo, qui direi che significa "male in arnese".

Comment: Io sono milanese e ho sempre sentito dire _strapenaà_, col significato generico di conciato male (come aspetto)

Comment: @CarLaTeX: E il significato è quello che ha spiegato CasaMich?

Comment: @Charo Più o meno sì, ma si può dire anche di una cosa, non solo di una persona.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: È curioso perché nella copia che ho a casa (Einaudi 2016), appare "strepenati", ma [qui](http://s6b1f1d7d3012cafe.jimcontent.com/download/version/1227982074/module/1132339216/name/ITA%2520Morte%2520Accidentale%2520Di%2520Un%2520Anarchico%2520Dario%2520Fo%2520(E-Book).pdf) si trova "strapenati".

Comment: @Charo Probabilmente, essendo di origine dialettale, si può dire in entrambi i modi, in dialetto le parole possono cambiare lievemente anche da un paesino a quello confinante...